# Python equivalent for given MATLAB code

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to rewrite a certain snippet of MATLAB for python as I'm not too comfortable using MATLAB.

```
a = 0.5 
b = 50
ph = (eps:a:b)
```

This is what I'm trying to convert to Python but the problem is I don't really know what the last line does. Hence I'm not able to proceed

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation for [`eps`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) and [`:`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MATLAB you are making a range of numbers from say `0` to `50` by `0.5` step. It can be done like this: `ph=0:0.5:50;`

For some reason (maybe having dividing by zero) you replace the `0` in the range with the smallest machine number `eps`, in MATLAB.

```
eps =

     2.220446049250313e-16
```

The equivalent in python can be the use of the `arange` function to make a range of numbers with a specific step ([arange doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)).
If you import `numpy` it can be something like this:

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(np.finfo(float).eps,50,0.5)
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, to include the endpoint, one way is to add one step to the range manually.

```
np.arange(np.finfo(float).eps,50+0.5,0.5)
```

By doing this, the endpoint would be `50.5` and the range will stop at `50` as you want.

Another alternative is to use `linspace` as follows:

```
np.linspace(np.finfo(float).eps, 50, 50/0.5+1, endpoint=True)
```

Here you can provide the `endpoint` to be included in the range. The disadvantage is that you need to define the number of elements instead of the stepsize ([linspace doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace)).

Both vectors should have the same size, you can check that:

```
np.shape(np.linspace(np.finfo(float).eps, 50, 50/0.5+1, endpoint=True))
(101,)
np.shape(np.arange(np.finfo(float).eps,50+0.5,0.5))
(101,)
```

Comment: So...what does it do?

Comment: the semantics of `arange` doesn't include the endpoint; beware. In other words, `1:2:5` in MATLAB is NOT the same as `np.arange(1,5,2)`

Comment: @JasonS true, fixed.